# game crashes when bullet hits the wall

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

In my pygame game, my player shoots "bullets" which are "pop()"-ed when they reach the edge of the screen, but if there is ever only 1 bullet reaching the end and nothing else in the array, the game instantly crashes.

```
    for i in reversed(range(len(shots))):
    shots[i].shoot()
    shots[i].drawBullet()


    if shots[i].x > swidth or shots[i].x < 0:
        shots.pop(i)

    if shots[i].y > sheight or shots[i].y < 0:
        shots.pop(i)
```

Comment: I assume that this is formatted incorrectly and that all the rest of the lines are supposed to be inside the fr loop?

Comment: Please format your code. The answer to your question may depend on indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean pop from list of python core:

Use "truth in value testing" on the list before calling pop. ie "if shots:".

Further more i highly recommend using something equivalent to "if len(shots) < i" at some point too before calling pop(i) on shots.

Recall pop returns the element removed and your code does not reflect that or comment its avoidance. I use a variable regardless like "discarded_i = shots.pop(i)" or comment "# surely will never need because xyz".